# Minimize $f(x_{0},...,x_{n+1})= \sum_{0\leq i \lt j \leq n+1}ln(\frac{1}{x_{j} - x_{i}})$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm working on this exercise and have some difficulties there:

For $-1 \leq x_{0} < x_{1} < ....< x_{n} < x_{n+1} \leq 1$ find the values for $(x_{0},...,x_{n+1})$, s.t. $f(x_{0},...,x_{n+1})= \sum_{0\leq i \lt j \leq n+1}ln(\frac{1}{x_{j} - x_{i}})$ is minimal.

1) I have shown that $x_{0}= -1$ and $x_{n+1} = 1$.

2) For p a polynomial, we should find the partial fraction of $\frac {p'}{p}$, I get here for $p(x) = \prod_{k=1}^n (x-x_{k})$ that $\frac {p'}{p} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-x_{k}}$.

3)One should set for $(x_{0},...,x_{n+1})$, s.t. f is minimal, $p(x)= \prod_{k=1}^n (x-x_{k})$ and one should use this to express the partial derivations of f.

I get for the partial derivations that $\frac{df}{dx_{I}} = - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}-x_{k}}$, how can I use p, what should I do here?

4) We have to show, that this $p$ satisfies the equation $(x^2 -1)*p''(x) + 4xp'(x)= Cp(x)$ and find $C$ and

5) Show $p(x)=DP_{n+1}'(x)$ for a $D \in \mathbb{R}$ and $P_{n+1}$ is the $(n+1).$ Legendre polynomial.

Unfortunately I'm stuck with 3), 4) and 5).

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you want to sum over $0\le i\lt j\le n+1$ since $i=j$ leads to difficulty.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I wanted to write $i < j$.